# What Did Steve Rogers Notice at the End of Captain America #6

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

As everyone knows, Captain America has been given a new past as a member of Hydra by the machinations of the Red Skull. However, his innate character is still unchanged, and he's planning to kill the Skull to stop the "corruption" of Hydra.

In Cap 6, he sees an image of his death in Washington DC, apparently at the hands of the new Spider-Man.

Surprisingly, "ruthless but still noble" Hydra Cap accepts his fate.

My question is, **why does he do so?** Am I missing something on the page?

[image: Penultimate Page]

[image: Final Page]

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what is the significance of the emblem on Spider-Man's glove in the final panel?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the final page marker, appears at the end of every issue; it's not actually part of the comic art. You can see it doesn't match the lighting and shape of the fist it's resting on.

Comment: Ah, the new Marvel, where Spider-Man kills Captain America for the glory of Hydra.

Comment: @Adamant: As opposed to the old Marvel, where Carol Danvers was mind raped (and actually raped) by a cosmic being and everyone smiled and hoped she'd live happily ever after?

Comment: @deworde - The old Marvel certainly had some serious problems. What I mean is that it seems like some recent events have been done purely for shock value. Character distortion in the name of "grittiness" a la the 90s and Miller.

Comment: @Adamant: Happy to have this discussion on a chat, but should probably keep it out of the comments. There's more going on in the Captains America than you see from the angry posts about Nazism.